# Vectorized implementation for Euclidean distance

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, euclidean-distance

I am trying to compute a vectorized implementation of Euclidean distance(between each element in X and Y using inner product). The data as follows:

```
X = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(10000, 5))
Y = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(10000, 5))
```

What I did was:

```
euclidean_distances_vectorized = np.array(np.sqrt(np.sum(X**2, axis=1) - 2 * np.dot(X, Y.T) + np.sum(Y**2, axis=1)))
```

Although this gives 'some output' the answer is wrong as each row still contains 5 elements.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko, what do you mean?

Comment: @feijao `scipy` has a function that computes pairwise euclidean distances between two arrays in a vectorized way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly this should do

```
np.linalg.norm(X - Y, axis=1)
```

Or with `einsum` (square root of the dot product of each difference pair along the first axis)

```
np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i...', X - Y, X - Y))
```

If you want all pairwise distances

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

cdist(X, Y)
```

Comment: Or `np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i...', *2*(X - Y,)))` so you don't calculate `X-Y` twice.

Comment: Also, `np.sqrt(ne.evaluate("(X - Y) ** 2").sum(1))` seems even faster with `numexpr`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer nice trick, didn't know about it. A bit obscure syntax though, shouldn't the interpreter do some kind of caching there?

Comment: Most of the time it's simpler to just create an intermediate `D = X-Y; np.sqrt ...` but the trick is useful for `lambda`s and one liners. Re the caching I'm not sure `X-Y` is officially guaranteed to always return the same answer, or have no side-effects, so I don't know whether the interpreter can rely on that.

Comment: Wow. You guys are amazing. Thank you.